# Brain stuck on overloading, How can I do this like a pythonista?

Tags: python

I know that I can't overload functions in python, and I can't seem to get my head around using python to get the behavior I'm after.

An Example:

```
class Hop(object):
   def __init__(self, variety, aa, qty, time):
      self.variety = variety
      self.aa = aa
      self.qty = qty
      self.time = time

class HopBill(object):
   hop_list = []
   def add(self, hop):
      self.hop_list.append(hop)
   # Where I would put an overloaded function?
   def add(self, variety, aa, qty, time):
      self.hop_list.append(Hop(variety, aa, qty, time))
```

I'm not really crazy about just using kwds and just adding a bunch of logic to decode what inputs my function received.

I'm getting the feeling there is a way better way of setting this up, anyone have any advice on how to take a more pythonic approach?

Thanks!

Comment: This is nearly incomprehensible without code examples.

Comment: And apart from that, you're talking about overloading not about overriding. Overriding would be re-defining a method that completely replaces (but may call into) the previous definition.

Comment: He wants to have a function that either takes an Egg, or create a new Egg based on the parameters of the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. Updated to use a code example and use the correct terminology

Comment: Looks like i don't know how to put in snippets, the spacing looked fine before I posted. How do i fix it?

Comment: It doesn't look like a good idea to me. Your class _needs_ a Hop object, why not just create it before you send it to the function?

Comment: eeek!  get that `hop_list = []` out of the class-level scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make two methods.  Init hop_list in __init__ or the instances of HopBill will share the list:

```
class HopBill(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.hop_list = []
   def add(self, hop):
      self.hop_list.append(hop)
   def addnew(self, variety, aa, qty, time):
      hop = Hop(variety, aa, qty, time)
      self.add(hop)
```

Comment: +1, the cleanest answer so far, the only answer without a clunky interface.  note that `addnew` uses `self.add` rather than duplicating the body of `self.add`.

Comment: +1 All overloading is is another way of choosing one of several functions to call. Simply giving the functions different names allows you to just use the usual way of choosing what function to call (name) for exactly the same effect.

Comment: @Ben: it doesn't give you the same effect.  What's the point of having duck typing for function arguments if you need to put the type of the argument in the function name?  There are far too many classes with "overloaded" methods like `addTree()` `addNode()` and `addList()` , which effectively prevent you from reaping the benefits duck typing.

Comment: @AndréCaron Duck typing is very different from defining multiple functions with different signatures with the same name. Duck typing is about just relying on a (preferably narrow) interface, not any particular type; so if you can handle a List, Tree, or Node with the same interface you just have `add(thing)` use that interface, and you automatically support anything else with that interface. If you **can't** support them all with the same interface, then "manually overloading" by using `isinstance` to check what you have does **not** give you all the benefits of Duck typing.

Comment: @Ben: I know they're different.  I said that not supporting overloads with the same name reduces the applicability of duck typing.  In this case, you could abstract the "lazy `Hop` creation" as either a tuple with the components or the hop instance itself, but you can't do that because Python doesn't support overloads.  In this case, the client code cannot perform this abstraction because it needs to encode which form it is using in the function's name.  Hence, you do *not* get the same effect as an overload.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Languages that actually support ad-hoc overloading do so based on **static** typing. The calling programmer has to know which function they're calling and provide the appropriate numbers/types of arguments, and the implementing programmer knows exactly what types/arguments they receive in each separate implementation. There is no analogy to Python duck typing, where the implementing programmer **tries to be somewhat agnostic about what type they're getting**, and the calling programmer may not know what it is either.

Comment: @Ben: I know how it works.  The relationship with duck typing in my comment was that you cannot have both duck typing and function overloads.  When you have dynamic typing, you immediately disable static overloads. My point is that with all of those constraints, you still do not get ad-hoc overloads like OP requested.  You just get *two separate methods with different names* and do not get "exactly the same effect" as your comment said.  Although this is the cleanest solution, it's just not what OP requested and it certainly does not achieve the same effect as function overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
class HopBill(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hop_list = []
    def add(self, hop_or_variety, aa=None, qty=None, time=None):
        if isinstance(hop_or_variety, Hop):
            assert aa is None, qty is None, time is None
            self.hop_list.append(hop_or_variety)
        else:
            self.hop_list.append(Hop(hop_or_variety, aa, qty, time))
```

Note also that I define `hop_list` in `__init__` rather than the class definition—otherwise all `HopBill`s will share the same `hop_list`.

Comment: I do not find this to be a "more pythonic approach", as the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an instance of eggs on the fly in a method of the Spam class.

this should do the work

```
def add(self, variety, aa, qty, time):
    new = Hop(variety, aa, qty, time)
    self.hop_list.append(new)
```

Comment: If i do this, I lose the ability to lazily add instance of Hop. I would like a way to either pass Hop, or (variety, aa, qty, time) depending on convenience. I realize I can't overload, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: in this case the pythonesque way is to make two funtions as mark tolonen say.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility:

```
class HopBill(object):
   hop_list = []
   def add(self, hop=None, variety=None, aa=None, qty=None, time=None):
      if hop:
         self.hop_list.append(hop)
      else:
         self.hop_list.append(Hop(variety, aa, qty, time))
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
hb = HopBill()
hb.add(Hop(1, 2, 3, 4))
hb.add(variety=5, aa=6, qty=7, time=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally favor Mark Tolonen's answer, but one possibility I haven't seen mentioned yet is:

```
class HopBill(object):
   hop_list = []
   def add(self, *params ):
       if len(params)==1 and type(params[0]) == Hop:
           self.hop_list.append( params[0] )
       else:
           self.hop_list.append( Hop(*params) )
```

This has the advantage that you can pass 1 or 4 params depending on your intended usage. There are disadvantages:

- If you don't pass one Hop object or four parameters then the error will be discovered in the `add` function where it complains that you aren't giving `Hop.__init__`  enough (or too many) parameters. It may not be obvious what the real problem is at that point.
- The caller has to know that the function really wants one or four parameters, and what those options mean.
- It gets a bit trickier if you want to support subclasses of Hop being passed in.

Mark Tolonen's answer fixes all these issues and is (in my humble opinion) more Pythonic. From "import this": "Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex. ... In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.".

Unless there is some reason where you absolutely must have the same name to call, I'd suggest you reorient your thinking to set aside overloading.